# How to show custom Windows message box buttons next to each other using Electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, messagebox

I am trying to make a message box using the Electron.js dialog method `showMessageBoxSync`. I would like the buttons to be 'Cancel' and 'Overwrite and Continue'. I would like it to display in the same way as the box does when the buttons are 'Cancel' and 'OK'.

When the buttons are 'Cancel' and 'OK', the buttons display side-by-side:

[image: Windows message box with OK and Cancel buttons side by side]

However when I try setting the buttons to 'Cancel' and 'Overwrite and Continue' the message box displays differently:

[image: Windows message box with Overwrite and Continue button displaying in a different part of the box to the Cancel button]

Is it possible to set the 'Overwrite and Continue' button to display the same way as the 'OK' button?

My code for the message box is:

```
const userSelection = dialog.showMessageBoxSync(mainWindow, {
    type: 'warning',
    title: 'User data already exists in this location',
    message: 'User data for the App already exists in this location. Do you want to overwrite it?',
    buttons: ['Cancel', 'Overwrite and Continue'],
    defaultId: 0,
    cancelId: 0
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `noLink` property described in the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxsyncbrowserwindow-options):

> `noLink` Boolean (optional) - On Windows Electron will try to figure out which one of the `buttons` are common buttons (like "Cancel" or "Yes"), and show the others as command links in the dialog. This can make the dialog appear in the style of modern Windows apps. If you don't like this behavior, you can set noLink to true.

So, in your case, you'd want to add `noLink: true` to your options object.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that in the docs - thanks very much :)